# Create vdisk in PERC H710 Mini under Debian 11

Tags: dell-perc, drac, dell-openmanage

I have a refurbished Dell R720 server with the PERC H710 Mini raid controller. I can assemble vdisks from physical disk in the BIOS. However, **I'd like to create a vdisk without rebooting**. I've installed Debian 11 and added the `srvadmin` tools using [these following instructions](https://linux.dell.com/repo/community/ubuntu/).

First, I've tried to manage the disks using the `idracadm7` command. Some resources indicate that there should be a `storage` subcommand, but not according to `idracadm7 help`.

I've found the `idracadm7 raid get xxx` command with which I can query information about virtual or physical disks or the controller. But this command seems to be read-only. The same is true when I connect remotely with `idracadm7 -r hostname -u user -p password` and a custom openssl config to allow TLSv1.0 and TLSv1.1. Here I'm a bit confused because the built-in help refers to the tool as `racadm` instead of `idracadm7`. I'm using `RACADM version 8.4.0`.

Finally, I've discovered `omconfig` for which I had to set `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` to openssl 1.0.0 libraries. However, here, the built-in help, doesn't show any subcommands even though I'm logged in as root and the dataeng service is running.

```
root@r720# omconfig -?
  
omconfig         Configures component properties.  
  
The available command(s) are:  
  
Command          Description  
Error! User has insufficient privileges to run command.
```

For me it's difficult to tell,

- which approach should work,
- which approach fails due to missing drivers,
- which approach fails because its a paid-subscription feature,
- which approach fails because the software is outdated (and libraries are incompatible), and
- which approach fails because the commands (like `storage`) describe a different version.

**How can I create a vdisk in PERC H710 Mini under Debian 11? Do you expect any of the above methods to work? What would you suggest to fix the issues?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> `apt install libncurses5` and `srvadmin-services.sh restart` and the wrong message about missing priviledges should go away, according to [this link](https://www.reddit.com/r/linuxadmin/comments/caq99w/debian_10buster_omreport_error_user_has/).

After that `omconfig storage vdisk -?` is the subcommand you are looking for.
The racadm-commands configure/show the iDRAC - not other components (in this case: storage).

Comment: Thanks, this worked. Additionally, I missed the `srvadmin-storageservices` package.